# What is pip's equivalent of `npm install package --save-dev`?

Tags: python, node.js, pip

In nodejs, I can do `npm install package --save-dev` to save the installed package into the package.

How do I achieve the same thing in Python package manager `pip`? I would like to save the package name and its version into, say, `requirements.pip` just after installing the package using something like `pip install package --save-dev requirements.pip`.

Comment: `pip freeze > requirements.pip`

Comment: This is not the same.
`npm install package --save-dev` combines both installation and addition to node_npm requirements file at the same time. It is more handy. With `pip freeze` I have to do two commands to do the same thing: 1) `pip install package` 2) `pip freeze > requirements.pip`

Comment: Pip has [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1479) about `--save` option.

Comment: If using setup.py for requirements, I have created a [small module](https://github.com/AdamGold/pypkgfreeze) to freeze your package versions into setup.py.

Comment: You can create an env and install your prod dependencies, and clone it to make dev env, and install dev dependencies. But you have to manually sync them. Or install dev dependency globally. It cannot be shared among developers, but it will be use full. Node.js does better in this case.

Answer (score 244):

There isn't an equivalent with `pip`.

Best way is to `pip install package && pip freeze > requirements.txt`

You can see all the available options on their [documentation page](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/).

If it really bothers you, it wouldn't be too difficult to write a custom bash script (`pips`) that takes a `-s` argument and freezes to your `requirements.txt` file automatically.

**Edit 1**

Since writing this there has been no change in providing an auto `--save-dev` option similar to NPM however Kenneth Reitz (author of `requests` and many more) has released some more info about a [better pip workflow](https://kennethreitz.org/essays/2016/02/25/a-better-pip-workflow) to better handle `pip` updates.

**Edit 2**

Linked from the "better pip workflow" article above it is now recommended to use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to manage requirements and virtual environments. Having used this a lot recently I would like to summarise how simple the transition is:

*Install `pipenv` (on Mac)*

```
brew install pipenv
```

*`pipenv` creates and manages it's own virtual environments so in a project with an existing `requirements.txt`, installing all requirements (I use Python3.7 but you can remove the `--three` if you do not) is as simple as:*

```
pipenv --three install
```

*Activating the virtualenv to run commands is also easy*

```
pipenv shell
```

*Installing requirements will automatically update the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`*

```
pipenv install <package>
```

*It's also possible to update out-of-date packages*

```
pipenv update
```

I highly recommend [checking it out](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics/) especially if coming from a `npm` background as it has a similar feel to `package.json` and `package-lock.json`

Comment: Note that this will also save dependencies of dependencies that over time might not be needed anymore because the dependency dropped the use of it.

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the --save-dev aspect of the original question which allows you to have different dependencies for local development vs production. How can you achieve that with pipenv?

Comment: @jeznag `pipenv` allows you to specify a `dev-packages` in your `Pipfile` and/or use `--dev` (or `-d`) from the command line. e.g. `pipenv install --dev nose2`

Answer (score 88):

This simple line is a starting point. You can easily built a bash command to reuse the PACKAGE in the line.

```
pip install PACKAGE && pip freeze | grep PACKAGE >> requirements.txt
```

Thanks to @devsnd for the simple bash function example:

```
function pip-install-save { 
    pip install $1 && pip freeze | grep $1 >> requirements.txt
}
```

To use it, just run:

```
pip-install-save some-package
```

Comment: My five cents `P=Flask pip install $P && pip freeze | grep $P >> requirements.txt`

Comment: What about the package-version?

Comment: The pip freeze command retrieve the package version aswell

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. I'm in a Windows environment, so here is a Powershell version of the bash function: `pip install $package; pip freeze | select-string $package -Raw >> $requirementsFile`.

Answer (score 9):

I've created python package that wraps around the actual `pip` called [`pipm`](https://github.com/jnoortheen/pipm). All `pip` commands will work as it is, plus they will be reflected in the requirements file. Unlike [`pip-save`](https://github.com/kgritesh/pip-save) (inactive for sometime), a similar tool I found and wasn't able to use, it can handle many files and environments(test, dev, production, etc. ). It also has a command to upgrade all/any of your dependencies.

### installation

`pipm install pkg-name`

### installation as development dependency

`pipm install pkg-name --dev`

### installation as testing dependency

`pipm install pkg-name --test`

### removal

`pipm uninstall pkg-name`

### update all your dependencies

`pipm update`

### install all your dependencies from the requirements file

`pipm install`

### including development dependencies

`pipm install --dev`

Comment: Actually, pretty interesting development!

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** apparently, [pipenv is not officially endorsed by Python maintainers](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2018/07/17/pipenv-promises-a-lot-delivers-very-little/), and the [previously-linked page](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/) is owned by a different organization. The tool has its pros and cons, but the below solution still achieves the result that the OP is seeking.

[pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/) is a dependency management tool that wraps `pip` and, among other things, provides what you're asking:

https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/#example-pipenv-workflow

> `$ pipenv install <package>`
>
> This will create a Pipfile if one doesn’t exist. If one does exist, it will automatically be edited with the new package your provided.

A `Pipfile` is a direct equivalent of `package.json`, while `Pipfile.lock` corresponds to `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 3):

you can **manually** save it in a Makefile (or a text file and then imported in your Makefile):

```
PYTHON=.venv/bin/python # path to pyphon
PIP=.venv/bin/pip # path to pip
SOURCE_VENV=. .venv/bin/activate


install:
    virtualenv .venv
    $(SOURCE_VENV) && $(PIP) install -e PACKAGE
    $(SOURCE_VENV) && $(PIP) install -r requirements.txt # other required packages
```

and then just run `make install`

Comment: I totally agree with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

How about make a shell function to do this ?
Add below code to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

```
pips() {
    local pkg=$1

    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "usage: pips <pkg name>"
        return 1
    fi

    local _ins="pip install $pkg"
    eval $_ins
    pip freeze | grep $pkg -i >> requirements.txt
}
```

then run `source ~/.profile` or `source ~/.bashrc` to import it to your current terminal

when you want to install && save a package, just run, for example `pips requests`.
after package was installed, its version will be save into `requirements.txt` in your current directory.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this small command line to install a package and save its version in `requirements.txt` : 
`pkg=package && pip install $pkg && echo $(pip freeze | grep -i $pkg) >> requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick hack on `pip` to add `--save` option to install/uninstall commands.

Please have a look at my blog for more information about this hack: 
http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2015/11/12/pip-save-npm-like-behaviour-to-pip/

Installation (GitHub):
https://github.com/abhiomkar/pip-save

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

```
pip freeze >> requirements.txt
```

Comment: This saves *everything* in your environment, not just the package you want to install.