# Handling development only dependencies with pipenv

Tags: python, pipenv

The answers to this question seemed to ignore the --save-dev part.
[What is pip's equivalent of `npm install package --save-dev`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135867/what-is-pips-equivalent-of-npm-install-package-save-dev)

I am using pipenv and have several packages that I only want to install during local development (e.g. pytest, unittest, matplotlib).

How can I achieve this using pipenv? I can't see anything about that on the manual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do can achieve this through pipenv: https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#pipenv-install

You can use `pipenv install --dev whatever`.

But actually I will not recommend `pipenv` as it handles locking very slowly. Which makes it almost useless.

Comment: What would you recommend?

Comment: Maybe `poetry`? I am now trying this one, and it is good so far.